# getting values from various formats and submitting to a Rails model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an index.html.erb page timesheet that has various js and jquery tables and functions. I want to take fields from the page and submit them to the database model i have in ruby/rails 3.

The fields i want from the page include a textfield that gets generated by javascript function, A Date that gets generated by a Span Div and an id that has to be found from plain text (or some other way). The values from these fields have to be inputted into a ruby on rails model called Efforts. I know how to do this normally in the controller by a function :

```
effort = Efforts.create!( 
:project_task_id => (get from the plain text ),
:User_id => current_user.id,
:week_commencing => (get from a span div),
:hours => (get from text field) )
```

The problem is getting the values i want that are able to be read by ruby in the format above.

code:
index.html.erb

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'demo_table2'%> 
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.dataTables2.min'%>


<fieldset>
<h1 class="head">Timesheet</h1>
<div class="left">
    <div class="week-picker"></div>
</div>
<div class="left">

<b>Project Selector</b>
<select id="project_selector" onchange="$.ajax('/projects/' + $('#project_selector').val() + '/project_tasks.js');">
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <option value="<%= project.id %>"><%= project.project_number %> <%= project.project_name %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>

<table border="2" width="" id='tasks' class='datatable'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id='tasks_tb'>
    <!--
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= project.project_number %></td>
            <td><%= project.project_name %></td>
            <td><%= link_to_function image_tag("icons/add.png"), "CreateNewRow('#{project.project_number}','#{project.project_name}')", :remote => true %></td>
        </tr>               
    <%- end -%>
    -->
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="right">
<b>Recently Viewed</b>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Project No.</th>
    <th>Project names</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><%= link_to image_tag("icons/add.png") %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <b><center>Hours for Week commencing: <span id="startDate"><%= Date.today.beginning_of_week.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></span></center></b>
</fieldset>

<!-- Task list table -->

<!-- Hours list table -->
<fieldset>

<div class="left">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Leave</td>
            <td><input class="dayinput" type="text" name="Leave" placeholder="0"></td>
        </t>
        <tr>
            <td>TOIL</td>
            <td><input class="dayinput" type="text" name="TOIL" placeholder="0"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sick</td>
            <td><input class="dayinput" type="text" name="Sick" placeholder="0"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td><input id="total" class="total_low" type="text" value="0" disabled="">
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    <div class="right">

    <b>Tasks this week</b>

    <ul id="task_list">
        <form name="frmMain" method="post">
        <table width="470" border="1" id="tbExp">
          <tr>
            <td><div align="left">Task Name</div></td>
            <td><div align="left">Hours </div></td>
            <td><div align="center"></div></td> 
          </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="hidden" name="hdnMaxLine" value="0">
        </form>
    </ul>
    <button>Submit</button>
</div>
</fieldset>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'timesheet'%>
```

js for addng a field

```
if( $('#effort_<%= @project_task.id %>').length == 0 )
  $('#task_list').append('<tr><td><%= @project_task.project.project_number %> <%= @project_task.project.project_name %> - <%= @project_task.task_name %>' +
                         '<td><%= text_field :effort, :hours, :name => 'effort_' + @project_task.id.to_s, :id => 'effort_' + @project_task.id.to_s %>' +
                         '<td><%= link_to image_tag('icons/delete.png') %></tr>' );
```

js for showing the tasks

```
$('#tasks_tb').html('');

<% @project.project_tasks.each do |task| %>
  $('#tasks_tb').append('<tr><td><%= task.task_name %><td><%= link_to image_tag("icons/add.png"), addtimesheettask_path( task.id ), :remote => true %>');
<% end %>
```

Am i barking up the wrong tree in the way i want to do this? im quite new to rails aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you want to do is very possible. What you're after is rails forms (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html). If you create a form via the rails helpers as per the guide, when you submit the form all the data from the various form fields will be available in the controller you've submitted the form to via the `params` hash.

All you will have to do is pull the various pieces of data from the params hash and construct your new model object. The steps you need to follow are:

- read the guide about form helpers to make sure you understand how that hangs together
- create a controller such as EffortsController, this will need at least two of the 7 restful actions (`new` and `create`), read about controller basics here (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)
- create some routes to map urls to your controller actions, read about routing here (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
- create a view using what you learned about forms
- when your page loads execute your javascript to generate whatever dynamic stuff you need, the goal for you is to make sure all pieces of data you want available to you end up in a form control, some of these might be visible some might be hidden (if you're pulling some information from another part of the page via javascript and don't want the user to see it)
- once you submit the form you will access to all the data you need

Comment: I know what your saying, but what im intially tring to do is to submit the attributes through the controller... do you know if theres a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean, submit through the controller, you submit TO a controller action. The controller action can then pull data out of the params hash and use it to construct a model object. If you're trying to do something different, you'll have to be a bit more specific.

Comment: sorry, what i mean is i have my variables which i want to pass to a method (in the controller), that then takes my variables and uses the create method from the efforts controller to create a record in the efforts model.

Comment: As I said, if you create your form properly, all the values from the various form elements will be available in your controller, in a hash called `params`. As long as you create the form correctly using rails helpers and submit it, you'll be able to output the params hash to the console and see all your data in there. You'll then be able to access your data e.g. `params[:var1]`, and pass those pieces of data to your model's create method.

Comment: Because of what ive done already i didnt want to go down the form route, but it seems like i will have too... thanks for the help